# How to create new environment elements using a for loop?

Tags: r

I would like to automatically create a number of elements inside a for loop, but still have them when the loop ends. The elements have to be named based on the loop variable.

```
for(i in letters){
  paste(c('student', i), collapse = '') = classroom[i]
}
```

however i get the following error message:

```
paste(c('student', i), collapse = '') = classroom[i] : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

is there a way to create and name new objects inside a for loop based on the loop variable?

Comment: Do not do this, I REPEAT, do not do this. Consider having everything in a container eg list/vector/matrices etc. But do not pollute the global environment with thousands of variables. Note that you can do this, but will it be worth it?

Comment: Agreed - this points to a bad workflow. I have a hard time thinking why this would be a better approach over just storing elements into a list.

Comment: I ended up making a list. To everyone worried I know it would pollute the environment, however in this case I just wanted to make 12 objects so wasn't that worried

Comment: @CaioThéodore It would certainly not pollute the env.